# Reload xserver-xorg-input-mouse

Tags: xorg, drivers, dynamic-loading

Can I reload `xserver-xorg-input-mouse` driver on the fly? For example, after I modify and recompile the source

Comment: I spent days searching for the same answer. I never did find it. I've tried: `xinput disable <device name>; rmmod psmouse` (replace binary in `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input`) `modprobe psmouse; xinput enable <device name>`. But I think it's still using the old driver. I must be missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an email from Peter Hutterer, who maintains a lot of the Xorg input stack:

> right now, you can't unload a module without restarting the server.
>   patches to support that were floating around at some point but never
>   got merged.

Comment: Thanks, did you find this answer or actually mailed him?

Comment: I mailed him about something else and asked this question as a side-note. If you really need it, you might be able to find those patches on the Xorg-devel list archive. I haven't looked...